# Moving to upstart from busybox causing the kernel panic

Tags: upstart, busybox, rootfs

We created simple linux file system using the busybox and it is working succesfully.

But we tried to move from busybox init process to upstart init. But we are facing the kernel panic, when we are trying to do `init=/sbin/init.upstart`. What could be the reason?

The upstart file image is created by upstart 0.3.9 package.

Comment: Can you provide the panic OOPS log?

Comment: Found that since we are running the filesystem through nfs.. that causing the issue. (not 100% sure). But when we created same file system with initramfs then it is working...